# How can I get this snippet to work?

Tags: groovy, metaprogramming, eval, porting

I'd like to port a little piece of code from Ruby to Groovy, and I'm stuck at this:

```
def given(array,closure) {
    closure.delegate = array
    closure()
}

given([1,2,3,4]) {
   findAll { it > 4}
}
```

Right now it dies with this message:

`Exception thrown: Cannot compare ConsoleScript0$_run_closure1 with value 'ConsoleScript0$_run_closure1@1e6743e' and java.lang.Integer with value '4'`.

I tried to set the closure's delegate to be the array, but it seems that in the `findAll` method, it represents a closure, instead of an actual item from the array. I also tried to run the closure like this:

```
array.with {
   closure(array)
}
```

but I still wasn't able to make it work. Any thoughts on what could work? Ruby's equivalent would be to `instance_eval` the closure in the array's context.

EDIT: Running Mykola's code produced this output:

```
given [1, 2, 3, 4]
class Demo$_main_closure1
2
Exception thrown: Cannot compare Demo$_main_closure1 with value 'Demo$_main_closure1@fe53cf' and java.lang.Integer with value '2'

groovy.lang.GroovyRuntimeException: Cannot compare Demo$_main_closure1 with value 'Demo$_main_closure1@fe53cf' and java.lang.Integer with value '2'

    at Demo$_main_closure1_closure2.doCall(ConsoleScript3:15)

    at Demo$_main_closure1.doCall(ConsoleScript3:15)

    at Demo$_main_closure1.doCall(ConsoleScript3)

    at Demo.given(ConsoleScript3:28)

    at Demo$given.callStatic(Unknown Source)

    at Demo.main(ConsoleScript3:12)
```

I'm running Groovy 1.6.5.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like a bug for me. Here is the code

```
class Demo {
   static def main(args) {
      given([1, 2, 3, 4]) {
          println getClass()
          println size()  
          grep { v -> v > 2 }  
      }
   }

   static def size() {
      return 2
   }

   static def given(object, closure) {
       println 'given ' + object

       closure.resolveStrategy = Closure.DELEGATE_ONLY
       closure.delegate = object
       closure()
   }
}
```

Which had to print (I tend to think) '4' as a size. And actually it prints if you will comment method 'size'.

You can read about `resolveStrategy` more and then let us know what wasn't set properly.

Comment: I've updated my question with the output of your code. Still doesn't work.

Comment: Yes. That's what I am talking about. Either I don't understand 'DELEGATE_ONLY' option or there is a bug in 1.6.5. I will try 1.6.4 at work tomorrow.

Comment: Thanks! Please post back after you got the chance to do so.

Comment: According to http://groovy.codehaus.org/api/groovy/lang/Closure.html#setResolveStrategy(int) the resolve strategy only works for properties. As grep findAll etc are methods setting the resolveStrategy property does not solve the problem.

Comment: the resolve strategy doesn't only work with properties, otherwise calling "println size()" in the closure wouldn’t work, but it does.

This is a groovy bug and a JIRA ticket should be opened on it.

def given(array,closure) {
    closure.resolveStrategy = Closure.DELEGATE_FIRST
    closure.delegate = array
    closure()
}

given([1,2,3,4,5]) { 
    assert 5 == size()
    assert [5] == findAll { it > 4}
}

Answer (score 1):

Simple - you are trying to call a closure passing it an array, where `findAll` should be called *on* the array itself.

Here are a couple of possible solutions. First one is straightforward:

```
def given(array,closure) {
    closure(array)
}

println "first way result: " +
given ( [1,2,3,4,5] ) { it.findAll { it > 4 } }
```

Or you can encapsulate `findAll` within a method body (that depends on what you are actually trying to do):

```
def given(array,closure) {
 array.findAll(closure)
}

println "second way result: " + 
given( [1,2,3,4,5] ) { it > 4 }
```

Here are the results of both:

```
first way result: [5]
second way result: [5]
```

Groove away!

Answer (score 1):

In this case the delegate object is a java.util.ArrayList object which does not have a forEach method.

Nevertheless the Groovy wrapper for this class has this method, but it is not used here (this seams to be a bug).

You can workaround this by using `delegate.forEach()`. I can see that this breaks the DSL you have in mind, but maybe it takes you a step closer.

The following code works for me:

```
def given(array,closure) {
    closure.delegate = array
    closure()
}

given([1,2,3,4]) {
   delegate.findAll { it > 4}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
array.with(closure)
```

Or if you want to keep your syntax:

```
def given(array,closure) {
    array.with(closure)
}
```